# Set a value to one of the props

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I use `Vue2` and `Vuetify`. I have a selector component that `extend`s the standard `VAutocomplete`. According to the logic of the component, I need to display `loading` when loading data. If you make a separate component, this is solved simply:

```html
<template><v-autocomplete :loading="loading" /></template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'CustomSelect',
  data() { return { loading: false } },
  methods: {
    methodWithLoading() {
      this.loading = true
      // do code...
      this.loading = false
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

In the case of the extension, the code will be as follows:

```html
<script>
import VAutocomplete from 'vuetify/lib/components/VAutocomplete'
export default VAutocomplete.extend({
  name: 'CustomSelect',
  methods: {
    methodWithLoading() {
      this.loading = true
      // do code...
      this.loading = false
    },
  },
})
</script>
```

`loading` works because there is a `loadable` mixin deep within `VAutocomplete` that has a `prop` `loading` in it. This `prop` is responsible for the loading lane, no local variable or method is used, i.e. the prop **directly** affects the loading lane.

And here begins the problem: I can't just change `this.loading` inside the component, because you can't put values of `props` directly.

How do I set the value of `this.loading` (I don't care if the parent component can overwrite it)?

Comment: This seems to be a regular two-way binding problem. Use an event to communicate with a parent instead of setting `loading` directly. If this doesn't fit the case then consider explaining it further.

Comment: @EstusFlask My problem is not related to a parent. I need to set `loading` inside this component to display the loading bar, and the parent has no effect on this.

Comment: Did you try `data() { return { loading: false } }` ? I didn't check how VAutocomplete  works internally but loading data should likely override a prop with the same name.

Comment: This gives the error that the given name overwrites the name from `props`.

Comment: In general, my question is rather general - can I (and how, if so) rewrite the `prop` component inside this component?

Comment: Is this really an error? IIRC this is allowed and this should be a warning. In general, you can't, props are readonly by design, so this should be solved for a specific component.